# method java.util.ArrayList.add(int,java.lang.Float) is not applicable

Tags: java, floating-point, arraylist

I want to add a `float` value to a `float` `ArrayList` through the `.add()` method. However, I'm getting this error...

```
no suitable method found for add(double)
method java.util.ArrayList.add(int,java.lang.Float) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method java.util.ArrayList.add(java.lang.Float) is not applicable
  (actual argument double cannot be converted to java.lang.Float by method invocation conversion)
```

This is my code...

```
class Exercise {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Float> floatList = new ArrayList<Float>();
        floatList.add(10.0);
        floatList.add(15.5);
        floatList.add(18.0);
        floatList.add(29.5);
        floatList.add(45.5);

        for(Float num : floatList){
            System.out.println("\n"+ num);
        }
    }
}
```

Could someone please help me with this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, java will use `double` for precision, if you want to supply float numbers, you have to do this:

```
ArrayList<Float> floatList = new ArrayList<Float>();
floatList.add(10.0f);
floatList.add(15.5f);
floatList.add(18.0f);
floatList.add(29.5f);
floatList.add(45.5f);
```

Comment: +1 - This is the fundamental mistake.  If the OP uses `float` literals rather than `double` literals, autoboxing will take care of turning the `float` values into `Float` instances.  But there is no type conversion path from `double` to `Float`.  (It would require a lossy conversion from a `double` to a `float` .... and that requires an explicit type cast.)

Answer (score 1):

It's because ArrayList can only hold Objects not primitives.  Remember, things such as int, float, boolean...etc are called primitives and they are NOT the same as objects. In order to get this to work, put your float into a Float wrapper as such:

Float myFloat = new Float(15.0f);

Comment: actually, java have a feature called Autobox for implicitly converting primitive types to Objects type (`int` to `Integer`, `double` to `Double, `float` to `Float`, etc).

Answer (score -2):

```
    import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.apache.commons.lang.math.NumberUtils;

/**
 *
 * @author electric grasshoper
 */
public class qweqweqweqwe {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Float floatList;
        ArrayList<Float> floatList = new ArrayList<Float>();
        floatList.add(10.0f);
        floatList.add(15.5f);
        floatList.add(18.0f);
        floatList.add(29.5f);
        floatList.add(45.5f);

        for(Float num : floatList){
            System.out.println("\n"+ num);
        }
  }
}
```

Comment: that's odd... why are you importing the classes from package java.sql. ?

Comment: -1 for code that has a lot of rubbish around it, and for not explaining what you changed or why you changed it.